# How do I combine multiple SQL rows into one in a select query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have data like so:

```
PersonID    Goal    
--------    ----    
1           one     
1           two 
1           three
2           alpha   
2           beta        

PersonID    Note
--------    ----
1           hello
1           world
2           i
2           like
2           squirrels
```

And I want to put all the goals and notes for each person into a single row:

```
PersonID    Goal 1  Goal 2  Goal 3  Note 1  Note 2  Note 3
--------    ------  ------  ------  ------  ------  ------
1           one     two     three   hello   world
2           alpha   beta            i       like    squirrels
```

With the maximum goal and note numbers computed to be equal to the maximum count of goals and notes belonging to any one person - so if I add a third person who has five goals then two more goal columns will be added, for instance.

Is there any way to write a SQL query that combines the rows in this fashion? Or do I have to do that sort of data manipulation in the application itself (as I am currently), which is slower?

edit: I'm using SQL Server and it would be OK to instead have a delimited list, e.g.

```
PersonID    Goals           Notes
--------    ------          ------ 
1           one|two|three   hello|world
2           alpha|beta      i|like|squirrels
```

Comment: check out pivot tables

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42397023/4892466

Comment: The only way to do an unknown number of columns is to use dynamic SQL. The specific implementation of that will depend on the database platform you're actually using.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to return an unknown amount of columns in sql.

What you CAN do is use is GROUP_CONCAT if you use mysql (other databases have other solutions)
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-group_concat-function/
You will end up with data like this.

```
PersonID    Goal            Note 
--------    --------------  ------------------
1           one,two,three   hello,world
2           alpha,beta      i,like,squirrels
```